# RadGridView not immediately updating DataSource when value is changed

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, datasource, radgridview

I'm using Telerik's RadControls for WinForms for my RadGridView component, and I have its' DataSource set to a list of Extra (custom object):

```
BindingList<Extra> extras;
```

In a function for refreshing the DataSource of the RadGridView:

```
var source = new BindingSource(extras, null);
extraGridView.DataSource = typeof(List<Extra>);
extraGridView.DataSource = source;
```

I have initialized the extras list in my initializer and everything I have works fine, except for one thing - when a value is changed in my RadGridView cells, namely a checkbox, the value does not update immediately after clicking, and I am required to click once more for the desired outcome.

I have tried extending my Extra class by INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyPropertyChanging, as well as calling the event whenever a value is updated, with no success. I have also tried calling several relevent events for the RadGridView object, but nothing seems to work. I have also tried to call the ListChanged event for BindingList.

None of these events work unless I click somewhere else on the RadGridView; it's as if the list doesn't actually change to begin with... This problem has been bothering me for the better part of 4 hours and to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem too.
I Found the anwer here
http://www.telerik.com/forums/gridview-value-change

I added

```
this.radGridView1.GridElement.Update(GridUINotifyAction.DataChanged);

// or (when the code above doesn't help)

this.radGridView1.MasterGridViewTemplate.Update(GridUINotifyAction.Reset);
```

to my RadGridView ValueChanged event and it worked.